# JavaFX/Swing Load WebPage Issue

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am creating an application, In the application I have three tabs, one which is a 'News' tab, which I simply want to load a webpage.

My code so far:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class BrowserPane extends JFXPanel{
    public BrowserPane() {
        final BrowserPane _this = this;
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

              BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
              WebView webComponent = new WebView();
              System.out.println("Loading URL!");
              webComponent.getEngine().load("http://www.google.com.au/");

              borderPane.setCenter(webComponent);
              Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,450,450);
              _this.setScene(scene);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Invoked like so:

```
contentArea.removeAll();
contentArea.revalidate();
contentArea.repaint();

newsPane = new BrowserPane();
newsPane.setBounds(0, 0, 1194, 593);
contentArea.add(newsPane);

contentArea.revalidate();
contentArea.repaint();
```

Now this works fine...the first time you click on the tab. But if you want to return to the tab later. It does not seem to render the webpage. I think this may be the way i am repainting the `contentArea` each time a tab is clicked.

**NOTE:** I am note using `JTabPanel` the tabs are simply `JButtons` that are styled as I like which invoke the various functions.

Comment: Why do you want to create a WebView, BorderPane and Scene every time you switch tabs? You can create them once and load the URL every time the user switches tabs or wants to load a new URL.

Comment: How would i achieve that? Thought it would be better to remove elements that aren't being used to save on memory

Comment: Is there a specific requirement that you introduce Swing as a dependency?

Comment: The application is uses Swing for GUI the JFXPanel is simply because I need HTML5 support and from what I read this is the best way (without spending money)